# how to sort numerically named subdirs in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I would like to sort the file ftog.sh containing:

```
cp ./8.17.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.17/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20.0.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.3.1/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
```

into this order:

```
cp ./8.3.1/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.17/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.17.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20.0.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You need version sorting for this:

```
sort -t/ -k2,2V file

cp ./8.3.1/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.17/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.17.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20.0.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
```

Comment: That has all numbers in same line. Try this: `sort -n < <(printf "%s\n" 8.19 8.2 8.20 8.20.0.2 8.2.0.1 8.2.1)`

Comment: did not work yet.. what I'm trying to do is have the 8.20.0.2 line display LAST from this list cp ./7.12/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.10/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.11.0.1/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.11/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20.0.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.20/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.3.1/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.5.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.5/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.7.0.2/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads
cp ./8.7.0.5/rpalorg.fmb /u01/SCT/testloads

Comment: Check my updated answer based on your edited question.

Comment: sort -t/ -k2,2V file worked like a champ!  this needs to be the top answer!

Comment: @jgraton: To make it top answer you need to click on tick mark which is on top-left of this answer. Once you click it will turn green and this acceptance will give you 2 bonus points as well.

Answer (score 0):

This command should solve:

```
ls | sort -g
```